# jTwitter, oAuth, and Google App Engine. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, noclassdeffounderror, jtwitter, signpost

I'm trying to use jTwitter to get an oauth instance to twitter with my consumer key/secret and access token/secret.  This is well documented in the javadoc [here](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/winterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient.html).  I have downloaded signpost, signpost-jetty, and the jtwitter library, but after deploying and running the servlet, I get a error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: winterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient`  Eclipse isn't complaining about the class not being there, because it is there-- I can see it in the JAR file itself, which is in my project.  So, I said forget it, I'll try out [OAuthScribeClient](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/winterwell/jtwitter/OAuthScribeClient.html) instead, but this generated a VERY SIMILAR ERROR `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scribe/oauth/Token`  This one confuses me even further because I have the following code in my java file, and it compiles without error or warning:

```
import org.scribe.oauth.Token;
Token token = new Token("myaccesstokeninfo", "accesstokensecret");
```

Clearly, I'm missing something very fundamental, but I am at an absolute loss as to what it may be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually "NoClassDefFoundError" happens when you forget to copy all jar-files to your "/war/WEB-INF/lib" directory, so those libs will be unavailable from server-side.

Comment: @ilia-akhmadullin I go the same problem, but my jar files are in the /war/web-inf/lib folder. I cannot resolve this issue. Are there any other reasons why this might happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Xo4yHaMope is probably right.

If you're working from Eclipse but running using a web container, then your runtime classpath might be different from your project classpath - which can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete Ben Winters answer what I actually did and worked is add the jar in
the libs folder within the project

see also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html) about folder hierarchy.

When you do this eclipse will normally add the jar to the android dependencies before launching the application. What I realise is that adding a jar in the build path will make classes available only during the build